# Empty MKMapView when switching from UITableView

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have a UITableView in a UINavigationController that contains a rightBarButtonItem which should hide the UITableView and show an MKMapView instead. The button seems to work great: it hides the UITableView, and shows the MKMapView. However, this MKMapView is empty. As in, completely white. I've tried to use a UILabel (just for testing purposes), and that doesn't appear either, so the problem must occur when I add the MKMapView (and UILabel) to the view hierarchy. Some relevant code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.mapView = [[MKMapView alloc] init];
    mapView.hidden = YES;

    [self.view addSubview:self.mapView];

    // Some other stuff, table set up, etc.
}
```

That is the viewDidLoad of a class that inherits from UITableViewController. Now, I use the following method that gets called when tapped on the rightBarButtonItem of the UINavigationController:

```
- (void) toggleView {

    if (self.mapView.isHidden) {

        self.mapView.hidden = NO;
        self.tableView.hidden = YES;
        self.viewButton.title = @"List";
    }

    else {

        self.mapView.hidden = YES;
        self.tableView.hidden = NO;
        self.viewButton.title = @"Map";
    }

}
```

I am certain that function gets called, I have checked using NSLog. Also, the UITableView correctly disappears, and, I assume, the MKMapView (or whatever other UIView object for that matter) appears, but is empty/completely white. Does anybody see why I'm not seeing maps when trying to switch to Map View?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should give it a size and position.
    CGSize size = self.view.frame.size;
    self.mapView =[[MKMapView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0, size.width, size.height)];

To check the size in the console, add the following line in your toogleview method:
    NSLog(@"%@", self.mapView);

Comment: I added that, and now it tells me the frame of `mapView` is 320 by 460, so that's correct. Also, it indicated that the object is not hidden, which makes me think the mapView wasn't (correctly) added to the subview, so the screen is white only because the tableView was hidden, and not because the map view is white. `[self.view addSubview:mapView]` looks right to me though..

Comment: What I would do now is logging the self.view and all its subviews. for (UIView* view in self.view.subviews) NSLog(@"%@", view); Another debugging technique for the views is changing the backgroundColor to actually see where are the views.

Comment: Anyway you shouldn't do it like that. You should create a view controller for your map and use either pushViewController or presentModalController.

Comment: I figured that was probably easier, so I did that. It works fine now, but I'm using addSubview and set the `hidden` property to YES or NO depending on what view the user picked. Does that have any (performance) up- or downside>

Comment: Speedwise I don't think so. But you may have problem with the memory warning process. You receive one memory warning per View controller,it lets you release views when memory is becoming low. If you have all your views, in one view controllers, you may find it difficult to release unused views.